# Independence of 3 Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that we have a random variable $X$ and we pull a random sample of size $3$ from it, which are denoted by $X_1,X_2,X_3$, then we know that all of these are independent. However, is it true that if we choose a new random variable to be $Y = X_1 + X_2$, will $Y$ and $X_3$ be independent? I would assume yes because $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $X_3$ and $f(X_1,X_2)$ are independent for any measurable function $f: \mathbb R^{2} \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok thanks. When you say measurable what does that exactly mean?

Comment: If you are not familiar with measure theory you can replace 'measurable' by 'continuous.'

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, I have not taken any course in measure theory yet.